# Map does not appear when using osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I was following this simple tutorial about using osmdroid:
http://www.gleisarbeiter.de/2011/03/17/using-openstreetmaps-with-osmdroid-on-android/

but whenever I run the application, using the Genymotion android emulator, or a real device, I just see grey titles rather than a map, as can be seen here:
[image]

My androidmanifest.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.picofoundry.nationalparksofjapan"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.picofoundry.nationalparksofjapan.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.picofoundry.nationalparksofjapan.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and MainActivity is:

```
package com.picofoundry.nationalparksofjapan;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MapView myOpenMapView;
private MapController myMapController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myOpenMapView = new MapView(this, 256);
    myOpenMapView.setClickable(true);
    myOpenMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    setContentView(myOpenMapView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default tile provider (Mapnik), then they very recently stopped providing tiles because of an incorrect user agent field in the request. Osmdroid version 4.1 fixes the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using 4.1, so I do not think that is the problem.

Comment: @Travis -Shame about that. On second inspection, you don't seem to be doing anything with the controller. Here is the smallest osmdroid example in another answer that I wrote. I know this works, you should be able to adapt it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162043/android-mapping-using-osmdroid-mapping-api/10162722#10162722

Comment: I quickly tried that code and noticed some strange behavior. When I tried it on the emulated Nexus S running 4.1.1 it had the same behavior as before. When I tried it on the Galaxy Nexus running 4.3 the map of London appeared. I am going to try wiping the Nexus S image and starting from a fresh install to see what happens.

Comment: I tried it again and it worked. So for now I am going to say it is fixed, but I am not really sure why.